# Huge size on mongodb's gridfs. Should I compact?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I've posted this question elsewhere as well with no answers and decided to try here as well. So here it goes:

I'm running mongodb and grid.fs to store small files (less than 20mbs). These are part of a replica set. I currently have more than 350000 files stored.

I've noticed that the chunks collection takes around 700GB of preallocated space where the actual chunks consist of ~40GB. Even though there are 700GB of data preallocated, this keeps expanding over time.

Keep in mind that every 15 minutes or so I delete files older than 5 days. So in theory my fs.chunks and fs.files size should remain around the same over time.

Here's my fs.chunks stats

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.fs.chunks.stats()
{
    "ns" : "collection.fs.chunks",
    "count" : 470388,
    "size" : 43295062144,
    "avgObjSize" : 92041.17057407927,
    "storageSize" : 757794040352,
    "numExtents" : 373,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 40356736,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 17431232,
        "files_id_1_n_1" : 22925504
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Is this behaviour normal ? Can I compact (defrag?) the chunks collection or even claim that preallocated space ? If I cannot reclaim that space (which I'm 99.9% sure I can't) is there a way to ensure that the preallocated space will be used eventually rather than keeps expanding ? Thanks!

Comment: You have to understand how preallocation works with mongo. The mongod instance will preallocate a new data file as soon as the first document is written to the last preallocated file. The reason for this behavior is to circumvent performance problems on systems which are missing the fallocate system call which just requires a few msecs(iirc) to complete, as opposed to several seconds filling a new datafile with zeroes. And even those few msecs are unnecessary latency, so the files are preallocated that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

**You could run the `compact` command on a single collection, or one by one in all the collections you want to shrink.**

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Compact+Command

```
db.runCommand( { compact : 'mycollectionname' } )
```

As noted in document, compact does not actually reclaim disk space, it only defragments and rebuilds collection and associated indexes.

**Use "--repair" option to validate / rebuild the data files** - This is susceptible to data loss if there is any corruption in the database. If you do not have enough space on the same mounted partition, you can use "--repairpath" to specify another location to build the compact files.

For example:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair --repairpath /data/db0
```

Shown here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/

**If this is a replica-set another option if the re-sync the node from another replica** - This will essentially build the entire database from the other replica node of the replica-set. You can find more details about this at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/.

Comment: Hey aks, thanks for the reply. Since this was a replica set I re-sync the node and it currently takes 25% of the actual space it had before. So yeah that worked just fine